# Drawing a continous line in a canvas Element

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I have a issue with drawing a Line in a Canvas Element with in HTML using Javascript.

Im creating the element the following way:

```
var canvasDiv = document.getElementById("canvasDiv");
var element = document.createElement("canvas");
canvasDiv.appendChild(element);
element.style.position = "absolute";
element.style.left = "0px";
element.style.top = "0px";
var ctx = element.getContext("2d");
```

And trying to draw it this way:

```
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.moveTo(StartpunktX,StartpunktY);
ctx.lineTo(Knick1X,Knick1Y);
ctx.lineTo(Knick2X,Knick2Y);
ctx.stroke();
```

The first line gets drawn (from the moveTo Statement to the first lineTo Statement) but im missing the second part of the line.

The values of the variables when executing lineTo() are the following: 
Knick1X: 350 
Knick1Y: 50 
Knick2X: 350 
Knick2Y: 250

So I should get a horizontal line and then a vertikal from that first line 90° down.

The canvasDiv element looks the following:

```
<div id="canvasDiv" style="position: relative;"></div>
```

Ty for your help

Jan

Comment: The generated canvas isn't large enough for the second line to be visible.  Set a width on the canvas greater than 350px.

Comment: Ty that fixed it

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing inherently wrong with your code.

Here is an implementation:

```js
var canvas = document.body.appendChild(document.createElement("canvas"));
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
var StartpunktX = 20;
var StartpunktY = 20;
var Knick1X = 40;
var Knick1Y = 140;
var Knick2X = 10;
var Knick2Y = 40;
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.moveTo(StartpunktX, StartpunktY);
ctx.lineTo(Knick1X, Knick1Y);
ctx.lineTo(Knick2X, Knick2Y);
ctx.stroke();
```

Comment: Your script works like its inteded, but somehow our still doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

If you change a bit the `Knick2X` value, you can see the second line:

```js
var canvasDiv = document.getElementById("canvasDiv");
var element = document.createElement("canvas");
canvasDiv.appendChild(element);
element.style.position = "absolute";
element.style.left = "0px";
element.style.top = "0px";
var ctx = element.getContext("2d");

var StartpunktX = 0;
var StartpunktY = 0;
var Knick1X = 350;
var Knick1Y = 50;
var Knick2X = 35;
var Knick2Y = 250;

ctx.beginPath();
ctx.moveTo(StartpunktX, StartpunktY);
ctx.lineTo(Knick1X, Knick1Y);
ctx.lineTo(Knick2X, Knick2Y);
ctx.stroke();
```

```html
<div id="canvasDiv" style="position: relative; border: 1px solid blue; height: 350px;width: 350px">
&nbsp;
</div>
```